# Comic strip about a human dressing as a robot and trying to infiltrate

Tags: story-identification, comics, robots, webcomics

A couple of days ago I came across this comic strip.

It's about an alternate world where a human dresses up like a bot and tries to infiltrate a bot community or something, then he is blocked by a door that says "prove you are not a human: enter the value of pi".

You can see bots walking in pairs on the left of the comic, and the human dressed as bot fretting near the door as he can't remember all the decimals in pi, on the right side of the comic. In the next panel, you see him calling someone (probably a boss), and telling him "sorry, the mission has been compromised".

The comic is not so detailed as Marvel's. It's a simple one, though not as plain as *The Oatmeal*. It does not have stick figures, rather proper drawings of the characters.

Comment: Infiltrating a robot community was something that Annie did in the [early days of Gunnerkrigg Court](http://www.gunnerkrigg.com/?p=208), but she did it by putting deely-boppers on her head and claiming they were antennas.

Comment: Sounds a bit like the 11th voyage of Ijon Tichy but I don't know of a comic strip version

Comment: ... there were no girls in the comic

Comment: I wonder how long a bot typically took to enter all those digits.

Comment: I'm reminded of the defunct webcomic SCP (Simulated Comic Product). The humans-impersonating-robots trope frequently appeared, as in this example via the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20090217211338/http://simulatedcomicproduct.com/2007/10/29/surrender-humanoid/ If that doesn't look right, you might have luck with the webcomic search engine ohnorobot.com if you can remember some keywords

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this might be from the daily comic [Commitstrip](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/?).
On July 6th, 2015 they published a strip called “[Meanwhile, in a parallel universe](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2015/07/06/meanwhile-in-a-parallel-universe/)
”.

The strip is a role reversal of how CAPTCHA works and jokes about how it might be implemented from the robots perspective.

Panel 1 shows the human dressed as a robot.

Panel 2 has the pair of robots walking by on the left.

Panel 5 has a sign that ask for the input of numbers and also the call to the boss where the human explain that the mission is compromised (or as he puts it, they are screwed).

The only major difference is that he does not need all the numbers of Pi, but "only" the sum all all odd numbers of Pi between 1 and 31415.

[image: Meanwhile in a parallell universe]